# why initAutocomplete function is not hitting for search place in google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I want to implement a search box in my webpage which includes a fullscreen map. I followed this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox and I did some code changes like below

I added this line of code in header

```
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"></script>
```

and html like this

```
<div id="map-container2" class="">
 <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Ville - Recherche">
 <div id="map" class="map2"></div>
</div>
```

and I added this function to my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

        });

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        alert(input);
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        alert(searchBox);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
        alert("1");

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function () {
            searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

    }

});
```

the problem  is that although I define `callback=initAutocomplete` in script tag, but it never hits this function. alerts whithin this functions never calls. 
I really appreciate any help. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get a javascript error `"initAutocomplete is not a function"` with the posted code ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/16er8mz3/)).  `InitAutocomplete` is local to the anonymous function run by the jquery `ready` function, but is never called there.

Either put that function in a scope where it can be found by the script loader callback ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/16er8mz3/2/)):

```html
<div id="map-container2" class="">
  <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Ville - Recherche">
  <div id="map" class="map2"></div>
</div>
<script>
  function initAutocomplete() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {});

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    alert(input);
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    alert(searchBox);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
    alert("1");

    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
      searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"></script>
```

Or remove the `&callback=initAutocomplete` from the script include, just use it in the jquery `ready` function, and call it there ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/16er8mz3/5/)).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="map-container2" class="">
  <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Ville - Recherche">
  <div id="map" class="map2"></div>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function initAutocomplete() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

      });

      // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
      var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
      alert(input);
      var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
      alert(searchBox);
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
      alert("1");

      // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
      map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
        searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
      });

    }
    initAutocomplete();
  });
</script>
```